# Django render can't locate a template that actually exists

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have the following view in my Django project:

```
import os
from django.shortcuts import render
from JumboDjango import settings

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    filename = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'frontend/source/public/index.html')
    return render(request, filename)
```

But, when it is called, it raises the following exception:

```
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/JumboDjangoProject/JumboDjangoVenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/JumboDjangoProject/JumboDjangoVenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/JumboDjangoProject/JumboDjangoVenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 74, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/JumboDjangoProject/JumboDjango/frontend/views.py", line 8, in index
    return render(request, filename)
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/JumboDjangoProject/JumboDjangoVenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 36, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/JumboDjangoProject/JumboDjangoVenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
    template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/JumboDjangoProject/JumboDjangoVenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 19, in get_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: /Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/JumboDjangoProject/JumboDjango/frontend/source/public/index.html
[26/Sep/2019 02:51:04] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 79956
```

You can see in the following image that `/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/JumboDjangoProject/JumboDjango/frontend/source/public/index.html` actually exists:

[image]

I don't know if I am missing any Django configuration, or something.

**EDIT**

This is my templates settings:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Can you add your **`TEMPLATES`** settings ?

Comment: There you are @JPG

Comment: Templates are not given as full path. Consult the documentation about the template lookup system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, You should always keep html files and static files (css, js, json) seperate.

this is good approch for me which I always use. For HTML files, define template directory in project folder.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        .
        .
        .

    },
]
```

This `templates` folder should be in project directory. inside this folder, you can create folder for your apps or anything. Like current case, a `public` folder inside `templates` and html file inside it. You can access this file like this:

```
return render(request, 'public/index.html')
```

**---Edit------**

For condition in this question, if **public** is folder where we will have all html files and **JumboDjango** is project directory, then:

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend/source/public/')],
            .
            .
            .

        },
    ]
```

**views.py**

```
return render(request, 'index.html')
```

if we create another folder inside **public** like **folder1**, then

```
return render(request, 'folder1/index.html')
```

But separate folder for static files is necessary.

Comment: Is this directory structure mandatory? Because I have some constraints to keep the current directory structure.

Comment: Hi @HuLuViCa, no it's not mandatory. I have updated my answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the directory to your `TEMPLATES` settings under the `DIRS` key.

It allows the Django template engine to look for template files in that folder.
For instance, if your template directory is `/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/JumboDjangoProject/JumboDjango/frontend/source`

So you need to add it as below to `DIRS`

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
             "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/JumboDjangoProject/JumboDjango/frontend/source"
        ],
        ...
        ...
    },
]
```

You need to render your template by giving the relative path to the `render` method.

```
import os
from django.shortcuts import render
from JumboDjango import settings

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, "public/index.html")  # Add a relative path to your template folder here.
```